# Decompiling from x86 assembly file

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, decompiling, decompiler

I have a program in x86 assembly which I want to decompile to a higher level language. I checked out [boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/) for that purpose, but it seems that it only takes binary files as input. What are my options here?

Comment: One obvious approach would be to assemble it using an x86 assembler, and then use boomerang on the resulting binary.

Comment: That is not working, the boomerang crashes!

Comment: Oh, that's sad. There are some other decompilation tools listed at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers ; you could try those.

Comment: @user1018562: Yes, boomerang expects binary code formats generated by standard high-level compilers so it not works with assembler generated code, unless your code simulate some high-level code!

Comment: Have you tried looking at http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a product which works from assembler called [Relogix](http://www.microapl.co.uk/asm2c/sample86.html), but I expect their pricing is geared towards enterprise customers with big code base and not single-file private users. From the free solutions, [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/) (somewhat dead) and [REC Studio](http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/rec.htm) (seems to be active) need some kind of compiled binary. [Hex-Rays](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) needs binary input as well (via IDA).